# Select component with ability to write custom value

Tags: material-ui

Hi is there any option that Material UI [Select](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field) component can accept custom string? To not force user to pick only existing value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `Select` component dont provide such functionality. For the same purpose I used the combination of two components: [TextField](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field) for custom string input and [IconMenu](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-menu) for select from the predefined values and set it to the input field.

And it looks almost the same:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I see this is an old post, but if anybody is looking for simpler solution you can use [this](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#free-solo) component with "freeSolo" prop:

> The textbox may contain any arbitrary value, but it is advantageous to suggest possible values to the user, e.g., a search field may suggest similar or previous searches to save the user time

That is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have got an awesome solution for this use [Autocomplete](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-write-and-select-qwe83?file=/src/App.js)

```
     <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-filled"
        options={top100Films.map(option => option.title)}
        fullWidth
        freeSolo
        onChange={e => console.log(e.target.value)}
        renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
```

here **options** are the array of options.

code sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-write-and-select-qwe83?file=/src/App.js